# A consequence of assuming the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $x$ be a positive integer.

Denote the *sum of divisors* of $x$ by
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \mid x}{d},$$
and the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ by
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x).$$

A number $N$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.  Euler proved that an *odd perfect number*, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form* $N = q^k n^2$, where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The *Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture* on odd perfect numbers predicts that $k=1$.

In the paper titled [Conditions equivalent to the Descartes–Frenicle–Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers – Part II](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-24/NNTDM-24-3-062-067.pdf), the following results are proved:

> > If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, then $k=1$ if and only if
> >     $$N = \bigg(\frac{q(q+1)}{2}\bigg)\cdot{D(n^2)}.$$
> >
> > If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, then $k=1$ if and only if
> >     $$N = \frac{n^2 \sigma(n^2)}{D(n^2)}.$$

Putting these two results together, we have that

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, then $k=1$ if and only if
>   $$\bigg(\frac{q(q+1)}{2}\bigg)\cdot{D(n^2)} = N = \frac{n^2 \sigma(n^2)}{D(n^2)}.$$

This last equation implies that $k=1$ if and only if
$$\bigg(D(n^2)\bigg)^2 = \frac{n^2}{(q+1)/2}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}.$$

Here is my question:

> Does the equation
>   $$\bigg(D(n^2)\bigg)^2 = \frac{n^2}{(q+1)/2}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}$$
>   imply that $(q+1)/2$ and $\sigma(n^2)/q$ are both squares?

Comment: In the paper titled [*Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers*](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) (Lemma 8, page 7), Broughan et al. show that if
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$, then $k=1$.

Comment: would a proof or a disproof of this conjecture be considered major in your opinion?

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @argamon.  The answer to your question is:  *"Yes,  either a proof or a disproof of this conjecture would be considered a major advance in our understanding of odd perfect numbers, in so far as no one has been able to come up with a proof in either direction."*